# Jaw to Jaw (without expressing action)

Tags: meaning

> As the werewolf wrenched itself free of the manacle binding it, the
> dog seized it about the neck and pulled it backwards, away from Ron
> and Pettigrew. They were locked, **jaw to jaw**, claws ripping at each
> other -

Research: I fully understand that if two animals are locked, they are holding onto each other.
And "jaw to jaw" means biting at each other snouts.

But for "jaw to jaw" to make sense, there should have been stated a verb as in "attacking, biting, etc."?

But simply "jaw to jaw" doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: Do you have an issue with “they were standing face to face”?

Comment: "The dog seized it about the neck" is biting. Both were biting **with** their jaws, not **on** the other's jaw.

Comment: It's probably meant figuratively, not literal.

Answer (score 0):

The collocation ***jaw to jaw*** doesn't have much currency with the sense of OP's cited example. If you search for it in Google Books, *most* of the hits will be references to Churchill's famous saying ***Jaw jaw is better than war war*** (or similar; it's irrelevant what the exact original words were).

But I found this 2009 reference to a boxing match...

> *The contest between Kobyashi and Chestnut was described as being “ jaw to jaw”...*
> note the "scare quotes" implying "not necessarily a well-known idiom"
> also note that a little further on, the text refers to...
> *a "cheek to cheek, jaw to jaw finish", a "photo finish"*
> ***also*** with scare quotes.

Personally, I can see the "literal" meaning making sense with two boxers jutting their aggressive jaws forward, but I can't really imagine two dogs "locking" their jaws together in a fight. Assuming the cited text is from Harry Potter, perhaps Rowling was influenced by the fact that we routinely talk about *other* animals ***locking horns*** in a fight.

Answer (score -1):

I'm curious, perhaps the author meant to say *Cheek by jowl*?

From [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheek_by_jowl)

> Adverb
>
> cheek by jowl
>
> In very close physical proximity, crowded together. quotations
> (by extension) In very close or intimate association.

Edit: On a second rereading, perhaps not. Just want to leave this idiom just in case.